# how to send response in json to a tree structure in servlet

Tags: java, json, servlet-3.0, simplejson

i am new to servlet and i succeeded to send a json format to the client using json-simple package/jar file; and import it like-

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
```

and to get response in json i have following code-

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("name", "veshraj joshi");
obj.put("id",request.getParameter("id"));
obj.put("num", new Integer(100));
obj.put("balance", new Double(1000.21));
out.println(obj);
```

and its format is like:

```
{"name":"veshraj joshi","id":"","num":"100","balance":"1000.21"}
```

and works fine,
but i need json format like-

```
{ status:"ok",
  message:"record has been added successfully",
  data:{
        name:"veshraj joshi",
        email:"email@gmail.com",
        address:"kathmandu, Nepal"
     }
 }
```

and dont have any idea how to achieve this in servlet;

Comment: You can use `toString(int indentFactor)` method of org.json.JSONObject. Here is the link: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString%28int%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine while try to make nested json and new code become-
response.setContentType("application/json");

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
obj1.put("email",'email@gmail.com');
obj1.put("name", "veshraj joshi");
obj1.put("id",request.getParameter("id"));
obj1.put("num", new Integer(100));
obj1.put("balance", new Double(1000.21));
obj.put("status","ok");
obj.put("message","record has been added successfully");
obj.put("data",obj1);
out.println(obj);
```